# Adding a delay in between each batch write using long write builder

Tags: android, rxandroidble

I'm trying to add a delay in between each batch write and I managed to get it working by modifying this [example](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble2/sample/example7_long_write/LongWriteExampleActivity.java) but I'm not sure this is the correct way to achieve this?

```
rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
              .setCharacteristicUuid(characteristic)
              .setBytes(data)
              .setWriteOperationAckStrategy(booleanObservable -> {
                  return Observable.zip(
                      Observable.timer(delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS).repeat()
                      ,booleanObservable, (callback0, aBoolean) -> aBoolean);
              })
              .build()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach would delay next (sub)writes if `Observable.timer().repeat()` would emit after the `booleanObservable`. Unfortunately that would work only for the second (sub)write as after that `.repeat()` would start to emit very quickly as it does not resubscribe to the upstream `Observable`. From `.repeat()` Javadoc:

> Returns an Observable that repeats the sequence of items emitted by the source ObservableSource indefinitely.

If you would use `Observable.timer(delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS).repeatWhen(completions -> completions)` or `Observable.interval(delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS)` then these would make writes happen not more frequent than `delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS` apart.

If you would like to give the peripheral `delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS` time before issuing next write then there seems to be a simpler approach:

```
rxBleConnection.createNewLongWriteBuilder()
    .setCharacteristicUuid(characteristic)
    .setBytes(data)
    .setWriteOperationAckStrategy(booleanObservable -> booleanObservable.delay(delayInMillis, MILLISECONDS))
    .build()
```

Comment: Thank you, it didn't feel right, I guess it "working" was just a side effect, perhaps overloading with emits was just slowing things down.Your solution is working great.